# Partly authenticating a docker registry

Tags: docker, nginx

I am trying to authenticate my distribution registry with `pull` being public and `push` behind auth. I am proxying the access with nginx.

This is my nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name registry.mydomain.com;
    access_log /etc/nginx/logs/dist-reg.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://registry-dist:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI     $request_uri;
        limit_except GET {
             auth_basic           "Restricted";
             auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd; 
        }
    }
}
```

Pulling works, login works, pushing does not (`unauthorized: authentication required`).

Applying auth registry wide (without limit_except) works too but that I do not want. How can I leave pulling from the registry open to the public but limit pushing?

EDIT: I am also unable to find any documentation on authenticating a docker registry with read/write permissions. It always seems to be either fully public or fully private. Any resources on the topic will be greatly appreciated!